# Seeked not working on flash source video.js

Tags: flash, video.js, seek

I have integrated video.js player and i have mp4 and flv videos in mp4 tracks seeking is working well but seeking is not working on flv source.

When i forward seek the pointer seek move forward but video still playing from old time duration.

please tell me how i can correct it.

Comment: Are you sure your FLV files are seekable? I've seen issues when flv files do not have key frames or metadata.

Comment: i don't know flv files are seekable. its a video.js player who seeked a video i think its not a problem of flv

Comment: Can you post an example that reproduces this?